# Performance difference between declaring variable as specific type or Variant

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to get a quicker macro if I declare some local variables as Variant rather than a specific type:

Originally:

```
Dim aTemplate As Excel.Workbook
Set aTemplate = Excel.Workbooks("blah.xlsx")
```

Changed to this:

```
Dim aTemplate As Variant
Set aTemplate = Excel.Workbooks("blah.xlsx")
```

Then this variable gets passed to other routines like so:

```
Call someOtherRoutine(aTemplate)
```

I have changed the receiver signature like so:

Originally:

```
Sub someOtherRoutine(ByRef aWorkBk As Object)...
```

Changed to this:

```
Sub someOtherRoutine(ByRef aWorkBk As Variant)...
```

Which change is giving me the performance gain and why?

Comment: `Which change is giving me the performance gain?` - neither. Try `Dim aTemplate As Excel.Workbook` and `Sub someOtherRoutine(ByVal aWorkBk As Excel.Workbook)`.

Comment: @GSerg via an accurate timer I'm definitely experiencing a gain through the changes I describe. I will use your suggestion to see if it is even quicker.

Comment: With `Object` you always get late binding, which is always slow. It might be that with `Variant` you can store a typed reference to the object which allows early binding, which is much faster but with a tiny overhead of handling a `VARIANT`. Using a properly typed variable removes even that little overhead.

Comment: Actually I don't think that sentence was correct. `Variant` should be late binding as well, and it should be a little slower than `Object`. Can you post a minimal complete benchmark that shows the problem?

Comment: @GSerg it is a very big routine. I also pass around ADO connections and recordsets via Objects bcause I'm using late binding with CreateObject. Are you saying if available I'm better using a reference to the ADO model?

Comment: Yes, use early binding whenever available. You have to have ADO components available on the system anyway, you are not making your code less depending on external components by not using early binding. Arguably, it is possible to [get bitten by early binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/10/03/yes-we-made-a-mistake-and-are-finally-going-to-fix-it.aspx) in a situation where late binding would do you fine, but the linked to case is the only one so far.

Comment: @GSerg ok - I will add a reference and test. Also I seem to have a performance drop after the first trip tot he server - simple loop which fetches about the same amount of data on each iteration, but the first round-trip is about three times faster than the second!?